# How to generate row echelon form of the incidence matrix of a directed graph in the most efficient way?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Consider the incidence matrix of a directed graph:

$${{I}_{kl}}=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & -1,\text{ if the vertex }{{v}_{l}}\text{ is the starting point of the edge }{{e}_{k}}\text{,} \\ 
 & \text{  }1,\text{ if }{{v}_{l}}\text{ is the endpoint of }{{e}_{k}}, \\ 
 & \text{  0}\text{, else}\text{.} \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$

How can I perform Gaussian elimination on the matrix $\mathbf{I}=\left\{ {{I}_{kl}} \right\}$ in the most efficient way (optimized in cpu time and memory)? Thank you for the answers!

Comment: "indicence matrix".... think to the respectability of this site.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Could you answer to my question, please?

Comment: I try sometimes to instil some humor : make some effort to be accessible to self-derision.

Comment: Now the serious things : may I ask you why you want to use Gaussian elimination ? To solve a system $I*V=W$ where $I$ is the vertices-edge incidence matrix, but could you say what are $V$ and $W$ ? It may help. You say also you have to implement it in an efficient way. But you  may know that describin a graph with an incidence matrix is, by far, not the most efficient way to represent even a moderately large graph in a digital computer...

Comment: Yes, I know that $I$ is a very sparse matrix, therefore its complete storing is not too efficient. I would like to get all possible combinations of the rows of $I$ which are zero. There might be supposed that the expansion coefficients in these combinations are zero or one.

Comment: Yes, I understand your joking. :P Anyway, have you any idea, please, how I can treat this problem without incidence matrix?

Comment: Look for linked lists (https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/graph-impl.html) or (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148313/what-is-the-most-space-efficient-way-to-implement-a-graph-data-structure) which are very close to **sparse** matrix representation. This sparse matrix representation is sometimes directly avalaible or you have to recreate it out of scratch...